# windows version through linux

Tags: multi-boot

How to find which windows(XP/VISTA/7) is installed in a dual(windows+linux) boot system through linux?

boot.ini is only present in XP.
Vista and Windows 7 contain a file name winload.exe in boot partition.

how to exactly find the correct version?

second, is it mandatory to install the windows(XP/VISTA/7) in a promary partition or boot partition?

I am new to these things. can anyone guide me or mention any article/book/links etc.

Thanks

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several static signs (i.e., not calling the `ver` command to get the OS version), that can clue you into which OS you have installed:

1. If there's a C:\Users folder than you're looking at a Windows Vista/7/2008
2. Presence of a "Program Files (x86)" folder means it's a 64bit OS
3. Presence of "C:\ProgramData" means it's 7/2008 (as opposed to "C:\Documents and Settings" in Vista).

As for your second question, yes, you need to install an OS on a boot partition - if you plan to boot it.

Comment: i know winXP is limited to booting from primary partitions, but i thought win-7 (and maybe vista too) can boot from a logical partition.

Comment: Any idea how to do it for versions 7 and newer?